# Delete/Remove Javascript user defined array from DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, browser

How can we Delete/Remove an JavaScript Array from the DOM/BOM defined in global scope?

with one of the temp array i don't want to occupy the browser memory after it has been used.

for example in a my.js file:

```
var my_array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];
delete my_array; //How to?
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: just in any .js file create a javascript array outside any function.

var my_array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'];

Now don't want to see it in DOM, remove completely. there should be no array with name my_array.

Comment: Do share your attempts mate...

Comment: @AmitShah What does that have to do with the DOM?

Comment: @Paulpro i am not sure where will it exists. but i can see it in Firebug's DOM tab. means it does exists and occupying browser's resources. i just want to remove it from there.

Comment: If your concern is freeing memory then `my_array = null` is enough to do it *unless there are other variables that reference the same array*. The variable would still exist, but the array would be garbage collected. `delete window.my_array` should remove the global variable, and then again *unless there are still other references to the array* then the array can be garbage collected and the memory freed.

Comment: Thank you all for asking example more in detail, but i got both the answers from @nnnnnn & Amresh-venugopal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROLOGUE**

The answer to this question is subjective to how the variable has been created.

JS `delete` can only delete properties of an object. Since you have mentioned browser, if you have used `var` keyword, like:

```
var array = ["some","thing"];
```

You can't delete it. **Ever.**

```
delete array; // returns false
```

Although, if your array happens to be a property of an object it can be deleted.

**Solution:**

1. Either use this array in an object.
2. Attach this array as a property of the window object.

   ```
   window.array = ["some","thing"];
   ```

Now, you can easily call delete on the window or other object you attached your array to, as:

```
delete window.array;
```

or

```
delete window['array'];
```

**EDIT**

Since you mention your variable is present in the global scope it is already attached to the window object. Can we still use `delete` on it?

```
var a = 2433;
console.log(window.a); //2433
delete window.a; //false !
```

By not using the var keyword, on the other hand:

```
x = 4657;
console.log(window.x); //4657
delete window.x //true
```

1. Variables created with `var` are an object in the global space.
2. Variables created without var become a property of the global object.

source:- [here](http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/31/javascript-is-hard-part-3-you-cant-delete-with-delete/)

Comment: Aren't global variables automatically properties of `window`?